# Clumsy Java Calc that won't compile

Tags: java

I'm a newbie at programming, so that this piece of code keeps me scratching my head as it won't compile. Net Beans suggests to add `return 0` and afterwards the code compiles successfully. However, the part after the printing to console   `Anything else to calculate?` couldn't handle the input properly, displaying `Please, enter a valid answer` regardless of the input data.

```
package calc;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calc {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Calculator();
    }

    static double sum (double val1, double val2){
        return val1 + val2;
    }

    static double substract (double val1, double val2) {
        return val1 - val2;
    }

    static double multiply (double val1, double val2) {
        return val1 * val2;
    }

    static double divide (double val1, double val2) {
        return val1 / val2;
    }

    public static double Calculator(){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" Enter the first number, please");
        double x = reader.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the second number, please");
        double y = reader.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter desired operation, please");
        char z = reader.next().charAt(0);
        switch(z)
        {
        case '+':
            double a = sum(x,y);
            System.out.println(a);
            break;
        case '-':
            double b = substract(x,y);
            System.out.println(b);
            break;
        case '*':
            double c = multiply(x,y);
            System.out.println(c);
            break;
        case '/':
            double d = divide (x,y);
            System.out.println(d);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Anything else to calculate?");
    Scanner reader2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Answer = reader2.nextLine();
    if (Answer == "yes") {
        Calculator();
    } else if (Answer == "no") {
        System.out.println("Thank you for using our Calculator app");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please, enter a valid answer");
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the return definition of `Calculator()` to `void` instead of `double` and it is fixed.

Comment: Thank you for editing and formatting code, it compiles now.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @M. le Rutte I'm sorry but the second part of the code went missing, so that I have added it back. Hope I didn't break any rules here by doing that

Comment: @jdv Thanks for submitting the article. Very useful for me as a newbie

Comment: No, that's fine. My bad when copying it to my IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't compare strings using `==` instead you use `equals()` or even better in this case `equalsIgnoreCase`

```
if (Answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
    Calculator();
} else if (Answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
    System.out.println("Thank you for using our Calculator app");
}
```

Comment: It worked.Thank you, for your help. Much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

Dear as the function Calculator is having a double return type so any how it should return a double value.But as per your code you are not returning anything
and simply printing the result in console so no need of defining the return type of function to double mark it as void.I hope this will make you understand the concept.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will  try to understand this concept better